# How can I host part of a site on another server and present as a directory off the URL?

Tags: domain-name-system, iis, amazon-ec2

A client would like us to build a microsite off of their domain.  The main web site is hosted on a MSFT IIS server on www.client.com URL.  We would like to develop the microsite using PHP on an EC2 instance. The URL for the microsite would be www.client.com/sweepstakes.

I am 95% certain that this can be done with a combo of HTTP server config and DNS.  But I'm not a sysadmin...

Thoughts???

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll need to setup ISA/FF-UAG to get this working the way your described. IIS doesn't have a "proxy" feature like Apache/Nginx/Everything-Else does. You could redirect sweepstakes.client.com to the other site using DNS, that's pretty easy. You can also redirect client.com/sweepstakes to sweepstakes.client.com, and thus end up in the right place.

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance :) ISA is Internet Security and Acceleration Server??  FF-UAG is Forefront Unified Access Gateway??

Comment: You got it! Sorry, was going to post a ton of link, then got pulled off on something else.

Answer (score 0):

As Chris mentions, a proxy feature is what you're looking for - most likely a reverse proxy with URL rewriting or similar.  IIS doesn't support this natively, but there are extensions/modules available that perform this for you.

A good site for learning more is [IIS.net](http://iis.net), and a good article on [the same site exists](http://learn.iis.net/page.aspx/659/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing/).

HTH.